# Is "Legacy Backup" in WHM necessary when you're running out of space?

Tags: server, cpanel, configuration, backups, whm

Lately I noticed that that my server's disk is running out of space, and that the `cpbackup` folder in `/backup` was around 277 GB. I have the Backup Configuration enabled, and then I checked the Legacy Backup Configuration and it was also enabled!

I was wondering if the Legacy Backup Configuration is necessary? Here are the configuration screenshots:

[image: legacy backup config]

[image: legacy backup config]

[image: backup config]

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if you are running out of disk space you potentially have more problems than legacy backups.  As someone who has waited too long to upgrade a server, I urge you to handle it sooner rather than later as if you require migration, it is impossible without spare disk space.

Legacy backup is as the name states, an older legacy system.  If you have the regular backup system enabled, then having the legacy system as well may be redundant.

There is a reason cPanel has relegate it to Legacy status, that is because it has been superseded.  It is always best to stay with the more current version if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Your first screenshot answers to your question:

> cPanel & WHM will deprecate the Legacy Backup system in the near
>   future. We **strongly** recommend that you upgrade to the new Backup
>   system.

As your Backup Configuration shows enabled, you've already done this. It's not only safe but recommended to stop using the Legacy Backup. When removed, it will stop anyway.